# Calculating matrix exponential by solving appropriate ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is known that the solution of the linear ODE $\frac{d\vec{y}}{dt}=A\vec{y}$ is the span of the columns of $e^{xA}$. This gives us a formula for solving the ODE by solving $e^{xA}$. However, is the reverse also possible? That is, can I calculate $e^{xA}$ by solving the ODE?

Comment: Sure.  The two are equivalent.

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked _how_ can I calculate the exponential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Euler's method (or one of the more sophisticated methods for solving an ODE initial value problem) to solve the $n$ initial value problems

$\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dt}&=Ay,\quad y(0)=e_{1}\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=Ay, \quad y(0)=e_{2}\\
\vdots&\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=Ay, \quad y(0)=e_{n}
\end{align*}$

where $e_{k}$ is the $k$th column of the identity matrix.  At time $x$, you'll get $n$ result vectors, which are the columns of $e^{xA}$.

There are many other methods for computing matrix exponentials.  You should definitely read the paper, ["Nineteen Dubious Ways To Compute The Matrix Exponential, 25 Years Later."](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf) by Cleve Moler and Charles Van Loan.